# Android spinner crash from NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I am building an app that has a spinner in it. The spinner is populated from an ArrayAdapter that holds data from an on-device database. Problem is, whenever i start the app it crashes immediately, without showing anything. I am completely sure this is a problem with the Spinner, because before i used it everything was fine.

LogCat:

```
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-30 12:56:23.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3945):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code (Activity that hold the spinner):

```
public class UserActivity extends Activity{

    private Spinner profiles;

    private String[] arrayspinner = new String[100];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.profiles);

        Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitProfile);

        final EditText profileName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ProfileName);

        profileName.setText("");

        this.profiles = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


        SetSql sqler = new SetSql(UserActivity.this);
        sqler.open();
        arrayspinner = sqler.getProfiles(); 
        sqler.close();

        if(arrayspinner==null){
            arrayspinner[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        ArrayAdapter array = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayspinner);
        profiles.setAdapter(array);

        //I am using the post method to make sure that this spinner wont run when the activity is started
        profiles.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                profiles.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(!arrayspinner[arg2].equals("No Profiles, Please Create One")){
                                String selected = arrayspinner[arg2];
                                Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, DPAActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("username", selected);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }

        });

        //the button listener
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = profileName.getText().toString();
                if(name.equals("")){
                    profileName.setHint("Please Enter Some Data Here");
                }else{
                    SetSql sqlobj = new SetSql(UserActivity.this);
                    //open a DB connection
                    sqlobj.open();
                    String[] profiledata2 = new String[100];
                    profiledata2 = sqlobj.getProfiles();
                    //setup a boolean to check if the profile name matches with one from the database
                    boolean isSame = false;
                    //run the check
                    if(profiledata2!=null){
                        for(int x=0; x<profiledata2.length; x++){
                            if(profiledata2[x].equals(name)){
                                isSame=true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //use the isSame variable!
                    if(isSame){
                        profileName.setHint("This profile name is already in use!");
                        //close connection
                        sqlobj.close();
                    }else{
                        //insert profile into DB
                        sqlobj.createProfile(name);
                        //close connection
                        sqlobj.close();

                        //setup intent and move to the next activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, DPAActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username", name);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, my code also has an option to put data in the array in case it is empty, so no null there (i hope).

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select your profile, Or create a new one!"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="New profile:"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ProfileName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Profile name..." >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SubmitProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Create!" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**EDIT**

So i made sure that my array isn't empty like you guys suggested, still crashing with the same error. Any help?

Comment: I think you might be missing a section in the stack trace. Is there more red text?

Comment: try using this

ArrayAdapter array = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayspinner);

instead of this ArrayAdapter array = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayspinner); and check

Comment: @arielschon12 Please check database value . before  this line arrayspinner = sqler.getProfiles(); in your code .you just call sqler.getProfiles() method and check database data.

Comment: it may cause if your arrayadapter is coming null. So, put spinner filling code in else part of 'if(arrayspinner==null){
            arrayspinner[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
        } else { <your code>}'

Comment: @G_S Tried it, no difference.. Same error

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I didn't miss a thing, it's all there

Comment: Where is getProfiles() ?

Comment: @G_S get profiles works, it is just a function that return a String Array from a mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the line that is crashing:

```
    if(arrayspinner==null){
        arrayspinner[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
    }
```

Essentially, you are making it either null, or not pointing to anything. Just set it up here, and remove the prior declaration.

```
    if(arrayspinner==null){
        arrayspinner = new String[100];
        arrayspinner[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
    }
```

Comment: Did this, it still crashes with this error:
11-30 18:41:10.661: E/AndroidRuntime(5279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 18:41:10.661: E/AndroidRuntime(5279): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 18:41:10.661: E/AndroidRuntime(5279):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)

Answer (score 0):

android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item in below code is the layout id.

```
    ArrayAdapter array = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayspinner);
    profiles.setAdapter(array);
```

The constructor here is public `ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`. Use the correct constructor. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Arrayspinner is not null if you initialize it at the beginning:

```
private String[] arrayspinner = new String[100];
```

it's just empty, and so it remains.

Answer (score 0):

**What's  SetSql() ?**

You should debug and find out what is null at line:

**ArrayAdapter array = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  arrayspinner);**

probably is  **"arrayspinner"**

If you are going to populate the spinner from a database query you must provide the choices trough a CursorAdapter and not an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: SetSql is a class i am using to communicate with my database. I can't see how arrayspinner is null because i am making sure it is not, so this is very weird..

Comment: ar you using a different thread in the sqler.getProfiles(); method??

Comment: if so maybe the close() is called before the getProfiles method returns the datas.

Answer (score 0):

Your arraySpinner contains null-Data, because only arrayspinner[0] contains data, but arrayspinner[1] to arrayspinner[99] contain null data. you have to create an array of the length of all your data, and then pass that array to your arrayadapter. something like this:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayspinner.length; i++)
{
    if(arrayspinner[i] != null)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
String[] replaceArray = new String[count];
int counter = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < arrayspinner.length; k++)
{
    if(arrayspinner[k] != null)
    {
        replaceArray[counter++] = arrayspinner[k];
    }
}
ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, replaceArray);
```

or you could set arrayspinner[1] to arrayspinner[99] to an empty string ""; which would give you 99 empty lines in the spinner;